# VULKAN - Uniform Buffers (Dynamic) - Rendering freezes and app crashes

Tags: c++, dynamic, buffer, vulkan, uniform

I got dynamic uniform buffers working last night.

In the code below, I initialize a dynamic offset, set the projection/view initially, then in a loop, set the dynamic offset to be i * the bufferSize, ubo's pvm matricies, then bind the descriptor set and draw.

This thing worked like a charm with a very random magic number I tried (21). But if I try 22 or higher, the thing just freezes and crashes. Just curious, is my approach to this incorrect? I must be missing something if I can't go over 21 loops. I have a GTX 3060 as well.

bufferSize for context is the size of the uniformBufferObject struct, which is just three mat4s (64 * 3 = 192).

```
        uint32_t dynamicOffset = 0;

        glm::mat4 proj = glm::perspective(fov, (float)screenWidth / (float)screenHeight, zNear, zFar);
        proj[1][1] *= -1;
        glm::mat4 view = glm::lookAt(glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 2.0f), glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f), glm::vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f));
            
        for (int i = 0; i < 21; i++)
        {
            dynamicOffset = bufferSize * i;

            // Update and draw the cube
            uniformBufferObject[i].proj = proj;
            uniformBufferObject[i].view = view;
            uniformBufferObject[i].model = glm::mat4(1.0f);
            uniformBufferObject[i].model = glm::translate(uniformBufferObject[i].model, glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, -3.0f));
            uniformBufferObject[i].model = glm::rotate(uniformBufferObject[i].model, 0.0f, glm::vec3(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f));
            uniformBufferObject[i].model = glm::scale(uniformBufferObject[i].model, glm::vec3(0.45f));
            
            vkCmdBindDescriptorSets(commandBuffer, VK_PIPELINE_BIND_POINT_GRAPHICS, graphicsPipelineLayout, 0, 1, &descriptorSet, 1, &dynamicOffset);
            vkCmdDraw(commandBuffer, static_cast<uint32_t>(vertices.size()), 1, 0, 0);
}
```

Trying to render hundreds of spheres using a dynamic UBO but when I try to access uniformBufferObject[where index = bufferSize (192) * 21 (4032)], the application crashes.

Uniform buffer creation code is here:

```
    void createUniformBuffer()
    {
        createBuffer(bufferSize, VK_BUFFER_USAGE_UNIFORM_BUFFER_BIT, VK_MEMORY_PROPERTY_HOST_VISIBLE_BIT | VK_MEMORY_PROPERTY_HOST_COHERENT_BIT, uniformBuffer, uniformBufferMemory);
        
        vkMapMemory(device, uniformBufferMemory, 0, bufferSize, 0, &uniformBufferMapped);
        uniformBufferObject = static_cast<UniformBufferObject*>(uniformBufferMapped);
    }
```

Create buffer function:

```
    void createBuffer(VkDeviceSize size, VkBufferUsageFlags usage, VkMemoryPropertyFlags properties, VkBuffer& buffer, VkDeviceMemory& bufferMemory) 
    {
        VkBufferCreateInfo bufferInfo{};
        bufferInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_BUFFER_CREATE_INFO;
        bufferInfo.size = size;
        bufferInfo.usage = usage;
        bufferInfo.sharingMode = VK_SHARING_MODE_EXCLUSIVE;

        vkCreateBuffer(device, &bufferInfo, nullptr, &buffer);

        VkMemoryRequirements memRequirements;
        vkGetBufferMemoryRequirements(device, buffer, &memRequirements);

        VkMemoryAllocateInfo allocInfo{};
        allocInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_MEMORY_ALLOCATE_INFO;
        allocInfo.allocationSize = memRequirements.size;
        allocInfo.memoryTypeIndex = findMemoryType(memRequirements.memoryTypeBits, properties);

        vkAllocateMemory(device, &allocInfo, nullptr, &bufferMemory);

        vkBindBufferMemory(device, buffer, bufferMemory, 0);
    }
```

findMemoryType function:

```
    uint32_t findMemoryType(uint32_t typeFilter, VkMemoryPropertyFlags properties) {
        VkPhysicalDeviceMemoryProperties memProperties;
        vkGetPhysicalDeviceMemoryProperties(physicalDevice, &memProperties);

        for (uint32_t i = 0; i < memProperties.memoryTypeCount; i++) {
            if ((typeFilter & (1 << i)) && (memProperties.memoryTypes[i].propertyFlags & properties) == properties) {
                return i;
            }
        }
    }
```

ubo struct, descriptorsetlayout, descriptorpool, descriptorwrite:

```
         struct UniformBufferObject 
        {
          glm::mat4 model;
          glm::mat4 view;
          glm::mat4 proj;
        };

        VkDescriptorSetLayoutBinding uboLayoutBinding{};
        uboLayoutBinding.binding = 0;
        uboLayoutBinding.descriptorCount = 1;
        uboLayoutBinding.descriptorType = VK_DESCRIPTOR_TYPE_UNIFORM_BUFFER_DYNAMIC;
        uboLayoutBinding.stageFlags = VK_SHADER_STAGE_VERTEX_BIT;

        std::array<VkDescriptorPoolSize, 2> poolSizes{};
        poolSizes[0].type = VK_DESCRIPTOR_TYPE_UNIFORM_BUFFER_DYNAMIC;
        poolSizes[0].descriptorCount = static_cast<uint32_t>(1);
        poolSizes[1].type = VK_DESCRIPTOR_TYPE_COMBINED_IMAGE_SAMPLER;
        poolSizes[1].descriptorCount = static_cast<uint32_t>(1);

        descriptorWrites[0].sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_WRITE_DESCRIPTOR_SET;
        descriptorWrites[0].dstSet = descriptorSet;
        descriptorWrites[0].dstBinding = 0;
        descriptorWrites[0].dstArrayElement = 0;
        descriptorWrites[0].descriptorType = VK_DESCRIPTOR_TYPE_UNIFORM_BUFFER_DYNAMIC;
        descriptorWrites[0].descriptorCount = 1;
        descriptorWrites[0].pBufferInfo = &bufferInfo;
```

Comment: You haven't included any of the code related to allocating the uniform buffer or it's memory.  Your problem occurs suspiciously when your offset crosses the 4k buffer (4096) so it's almost certainly related to how you're allocating and handling the UBO memory.  You're also not showing where you're pushing the CPU data to the GPU UBO memory, so there's not a lot to work with here in terms of diagnosis.

Comment: I thought I saved all my edits. I added some more info.

Answer (score 1):

> `createBuffer(bufferSize, ...`

Assuming this is the same `bufferSize` as your loop that populates the structure, this needs to be

`createBuffer(bufferSize * <whatever number of draws you want active>, ...`

You're allocating a single 192 byte buffer, which happens to be at the start of a page, and so you you are able write over the end of the buffer until you hit the end of the page which then faults.

Comment: shoot man, I must have missed that. Thank you.

Comment: I cant upvote your answer btw since I am apparently a newb. I recommend everyone else that exceeds the rep quota do it though